# Django Importing Random Libraries?

Tags: python, django, debugging, import, shared-libraries

Sometimes when I recompile or rerun my Django application, Django will import libraries at random that it then can't find.

ie

```
from cgi import test
from distutils.command.clean import clean
from winreg import SetValue
```

```
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pweyand/NEST/lightchan/lightchan/backend/lightchan/lightone/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/pweyand/NEST/lightchan/lightchan/backend/lightchan/lightone/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from winreg import SetValue
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'
```

What gives? Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: What's random about the `winreg` import?

Comment: Well... I don't know what it is off the top of my head, I don't need it in my project, it auto imports and throws an error? That sorta sucks. I don't want Django to do that.

Comment: That's not entirely true. It's being imported by `"/home/pweyand/NEST/lightchan/lightchan/backend/lightchan/lightone/views.py"` so it is needed, but it's not installed.

Comment: It's imported...but I don't *need* it in the application. And it's throwing an error. It's not needed in the sense that nothing in my application is using it and it throws an error. If I just delete the line, the code runs, so there isn't any code that needs it to run. The auto-importer is wigging out.

Comment: If it's an unused import, then it's good practice to remove it.

Comment: Yes...Django is auto-importing these libraries. So...

Comment: `winreg` is a dependency of `lightchan` based on what you've posted. Packages import what they need to operate. Those imported packages are called dependencies and they're either standard library (included in python itself) or they need to be installed via pip. `winreg` needs to be installed via pip, so the simple approach is to just install all dependencies. Otherwise you need to change your dependencies so that you don't need to install theirs.

Comment: You're not understanding the question. It's OK, don't worry about it.